# What would be the impact of Connecting two application to the same database using same datasource in java?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, jboss

There are 2 different applications running on the same jboss server. I want to connect these 2 applications with the same mysql database through the same data source.

what kind of impact can be occur in running these 2 application -

I am supposing that these issues could be happen .
 - Table Locking issues, Slow performance, connectivity issue, ACID properties lost issue.

Are there any drawbacks with this approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing of this can happen (Table Locking issues, Slow performance, connectivity issue, ACID properties lost issue).

The database cannot really distinguish if two connections come from the same application.

Of course, two applications still means twice as many requests, so performance may be affected. ACIDity is not affected and you are unlikely to run out of TCP ports either.

**The performance of two apps accessing the same database is the same as the performance of one app twice as popular**.

Answer (score 1):

There are no drawbacks, as long as there are enough connections for both apps and your transactions are well written its normal to share the same datasource

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should consider if there are any advantages?

In my opinion there is have to be compelling reasons to *not* create separate datasources for separate applications - I sense that this is not the case for you.

In any case, some of the drawbacks you mention may happen when you share a connection pool between applications or when you don't since they are properties of the *database* not the *connections*.

**Edit**: Summarizing the good discussion with Jan Dvorak below, here are some arguments for using one (or more) datasources per application:

- It enables one to discard eg. stale or appserver-culled connections (-threads) from one application without affecting others
- Having multiple DS'es per application enables one to reset admin connections without affecting production connections.

Cheers,

Comment: "compelling reasons to not create separate datasources" such as cash to actually buy or rent an extra machine?

Comment: I meant datasources as in the AppServer JNDI sense, not the 4U rack iron sense :-)

Comment: In this case it may be beficial from the performance standpoint to use the same database (as in "mysqld process").

Comment: Jan, that still does not conflict with my statement. There may be two apps on the appserver, using two different DS'es in the JNDI tree, and both of the DS'es may reference the same physical database instance (cf. "mysqld process"). Such a setup would not cause any performance degradation compared to sharing a single DS.

Comment: I can agree with this. In this case, there are no drawbacks but not benefits either. I believe OP didn't mean JNDI tree entries, however, but rather mysqld instances.

Comment: I don't agree that there are no benefits - how about being able to throw out all connections from one pool while not touching those running for the other application? This is a perfectly valid real-world use-case of which I have personal experience...

Comment: I will agree with that :-) Cheers,

Comment: What about extending this argument and saying it might be beneficial to create multiple JNDI resources per application, so you could reset admin connections without affecting the users? :-)

Answer (score 0):

The main issue would be with pooling. As more applications use the datasource, more connections are open so the default pool may not be enough.

Apart from that, all the other issues are related to the DB engine and your DB design than to the datasource. A DB engine won't stop being ACID compliant no matter how it is accessed, won't be slower than if the accesses were from different datasources, and so on...