# Using two data access in same project

Tags: .net, ado.net, asp.net-identity

I'm wondering if i can work with two different data access in the same project?

this is the scenario:

I'm working in a web application using .net core as back-end and Angular 2 as front-end, 
now in my SQL database i use alot of Stored Procedures, i face a difficulty to use Stored Procedure and views using [Code-First/ DB first], and i used to work with native Ado.net sql commands in my previous project.

So my problem arised when i need to use the MS Identity for authentication and authorization, i figured out that using identiy worked with Entity Framework, Identity will use DBContext to query database using connection string.

My point is if i use the same connection string that is used by Identity framework to query my database with native Ado.net sq commands.

Is this a bad practice or it's slows the performance, is there any conflict will appeare if i use two data access pointing to the SAME database for the same project.

Comment: I work on legacy program and we use both, ADO.NET and ET but I found a one problem on long queries we have a deadlock on database.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will not any confliction. You use same database but ado and entity have different two DbContext. For exp your Entity DbContext can not use from Ado.Net.

Your situation is similar with these links.

[What would be the impact of Connecting two application to the same database using same datasource in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13119693/what-would-be-the-impact-of-connecting-two-application-to-the-same-database-usin)

Comment: I need an accurate answer please,  can i run application that use the same database but using two different access layers, one is ADO.net and the other is Entity Framework, where entity framework is used to work with identity?

Comment: I think that is possible, you can use two or more access layer, this is possible as programaticly only one condition is required, use your imegination ;)  By the way, you can programaticly create connection between Ado.net and Entity freamwork with c# classess.. For ex; Step1:))Use ado.net connection and read some data __ Step2::)) Add this data to c# variable and dispose ado.net connection__ Step3:)) Use EntityFreamwork connection and add c# variable content to database that connected via Ef....